# Selecionar elemento através de parte de atributo contido nele

Tags: javascript, jquery, atributos

Possuo um elemento, por exemplo:

```
<div class="teste" data-info="isflaolatesteum"></div>
```

E, para selecioná-lo, poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$(".teste[data-info='isflaolatesteum']")...
```

Porém, eu quero selecionar esse elemento através do atributo (data-info) só que eu possuo apenas parte da string contida no atributo. Como no exemplo acima, gostaria de selecionar todos os elementos que contenham `teste` no meio do atributo, ou seja, seria como um indexOf no atributo.

Isso é possível?

Comment: No começo é tudo muito lindo, mas a dor de cabeça vem depois, recomendo que leia isso.  http://intuio.at/en/blog/dont-use-data-attributes-to-find-html-elements-with-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o seletor [contains do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) para isso.
`*=` no seletor de atributo quer dizer "que contêm o texto".

No teu caso seria

```
$(".teste[data-info*='teste']")
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/t8n66jb1/

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!